# Can I use an Expression to set a variable in a "SQL Statement Task"?

Tags: variables, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, expression

Can I use an Expression to set a variable in a "SQL Statement Task" ?
I am designed an ETL solution loading a plain text file from a website. The user write the main parameters, like month, year, registercount, and press the processing button. The ETL solution starts.

Until now, I am used to read/set variables with SQL statements inside same "SQL Statement Task" but sometimes they do not work properly when the solution is started from the web app with these same params used to set these variables. I have no problem to read variables in an expression but I am not able to write them.

Comment: This question could use some more clarification.  I get that you're having a problem setting parameters in a sql task, but could you provide how the task is configured and give an example of when it does not work?  Is there any consistency to when it does work?

Comment: Sorry Mark Wojciechowicz about my short explanations, I am new with stack and I was seeking a solution to my problem. I think Tyron78 answer is right and the variable is taking the right values.

Comment: I´d like to add an image but I don't have enough points. The problem was I didn't see the real value when I was debbuging. I learn to watch the variables while debbuging with a "select" containing the variables that I need to check.
Sorry for the inconvenience. Finally my solution is ended and running properly.

Comment: You can also set a breakpoint on the component and check the values of the variables in the locals window.

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you very much. That was my problem. The values in the "Variables" windows are not always updated, if they are empty at start time when package starts they are correctly updated but they aren't and stand old values. I must use the "Locals" windows to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about the "Execute SQL Task", expressions are possible. Here what I usually do is to configure the type as "direct input" and then define the whole statement - including my parametrized values - as expression. If you rightclick the task, you can select properties and in the properties you open the expression popup by clicking the "+" left of "Expressions" and then "..." which appears right of it. Then after selecting the property "SqlStatementSource" you can click the "..." at the right again and enter your expression here.

Comment: How well does the debugging experience go when using this approach?

Comment: Well, the debugging experience is for sure enhanced, if you define a string variable with the expression on it and then select SQL command from variable instead of direct input - then you can put a watch on the variable value and track as it changes...

Comment: So, did you succeed in debugging?

Comment: Oh, I've dabbled with SSIS [a bit](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ssis/topusers). I too have found that debugging an expression that is attached to an executable an impossible task and wanted to see if you had a solution that I hadn't encountered. The creation of a variable that has all the expressions applied and is subsequently used by the executable seems the only reasonable approach. I was hoping you'd add that into your answer

Comment: Ok, answer submitted. Accepting it would be kind of you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the debugging experience is for sure enhanced, if you define a string variable with the expression on it and then select SQL command from variable instead of direct input - then you can put a watch on the variable value and track as it changes...